# Using State.modify from another function

Tags: haskell, template-haskell

It is only a skeleton of program. I have main function, that

```
State [Dec] [Dec]
mainCon = do
  acc <- get
  put []
  modify $ (++) [some func]
  return acc
```

On one stage I call function:

```
foldlWithKey'
                         (\list' key' val' ->
    if (...)
          then
                (Control.Monad.State.modify $ (Prelude.++) [elem]) >>
                some code
                : list')
          else
                (Control.Monad.State.modify $ (Prelude.++) []) >>
                some code
                : list')
                             )
                             []
                             (map')
```

and want to modify State in mainCon, but continue traverse map'. The error is:

```
No instance for (MonadState [Dec] [])
      arising from a use of ‘Control.Monad.State.modify’
    In the expression: Control.Monad.State.modify
```

[Dec] from Template Haskell. How can I simply solve this problem?

Comment: What's the type signature of `foldWithKey'`?

Comment: @ErikR foldlWithKey' :: (a -> k -> v -> a) -> a -> HashMap k v -> a

Answer (score 1):

Conceptually the problem is that  the
first argument passed to `foldWithKey'` must be a pure function,
but when you use `modify` you are creating a stateful computation,
not a pure function.

Apparently you are trying to iterate through a hashmap while
maintaining some state during the traversal. `foldWithKey'`
already gives you that state - it's the first parameter to
the accumulation function:

```
                  v-- current state
foldlWithKey' :: (a -> k -> v -> a) -> a -> HashMap k v -> a
                     new state --^     ^-- initial         ^-- final
                                           state               state
```

The accumulation function takes the current state, a key and a value
and returns an updated state. Then if you give `foldWithKey'` an initial
state it will return the final state.

Here's an example using `foldWithKey` which is the same as
`foldWithKey'` except that the arguments are in a slightly
different order.

The function`evenOdds` returns two lists - one containing
the keys which have even values and those which have odd values.

The state is the pair `(even,odds)`, and the accumulation function `go`
returns the updated state based on the current key and value.

```
 {-# LANGUAGE NoMonomorphismRestriction #-}

 import qualified Data.HashMap as H

 myMap = H.fromList [ ("a",1), ("b",2), ("c",3), ("d",4) ]

 evenOdds :: ([String],[String])
 evenOdds = H.foldWithKey go ([],[]) myMap
   where  go :: String -> Int -> ([String],[String]) -> ([String],[String])
          go k a (evens,odds) = 
             if even a then ( evens ++ [k], odds)
                       else ( evens       , odds ++ [k] )
```